# curl error HTTP status code 0-- empty reply from server

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to scrap a website but it always said that `Empty Reply from server`
can any one look at the `code` and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is the `code`

```
function spider($url){
        $header = array(
            "Host" => "www.example.net",
            //"Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch",
            "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8",
            "Cache-Control:max-age=0",
            "Connection:keep-alive","Content-Length:725","Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
            ,"X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest"
        );
        $cookie = "cookie.txt";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // return headers 0 no 1 yes
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return page 1:yes
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200); // http request time-out 20 seconds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Follow redirects, need this if the URL changes
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2); //if http server gives redirection response
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath( $cookie)); // cookies storage / here the changes have been made
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath( $cookie));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // false for https
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"view=ViewDistrict&param=7&uniqueid=1397991494188&PHPSESSID=f134vrnv7glosgojvf4n1mp7o2&page=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fxhr.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.com/");
        $data = curl_exec($ch); // execute the http request
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch); // close the connection

        return $data;
}
```

Here is `function call`

```
echo spider("http://www.example.net/");
```

**Edit**

```
Array ( [url] => http://www.example.net/ [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 301 [header_size] => 196 [request_size] => 840 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 1 [total_time] => 61.359 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.281 [pretransfer_time] => 0.281 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 178 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 60.593 [redirect_time] => 0.766 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [redirect_url] => ) Empty reply from server
```

this is the header now
also I'd updated my `post data`
it's now 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"view=ViewDistrict&param=7&uniqueid=".time().  rand(101,500)."&PHPSESSID=f134vrnv7glosgojvf4n1mp7o2&page=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fxhr.php");`

and also had removed `"X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest"` from `headers`

Comment: Are the post values still valid ?  does it have more than 2 redirs ? is your server blocked ? what are the headers returned ?

Comment: yes these are valid, and no It have no `redirect`

Comment: I'll update the question with the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing this from the headers ?

```
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem is in this line:

```
curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    "view=ViewDistrict&param=7&uniqueid=1397991494188&PHPSESSID=f134vrnv7glosgojvf4n1mp7o2&page=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fxhr.php"
);
```

Notice that you're passing a value for `PHPSESSID`. I'm guessing you copied & pasted a URL from a visit to the site, right? That session ID was probably valid when you visited the site, but the odds of it being valid now are pretty slim. And if the server doesn't like the session ID, chances are it's not going to give you any data.

Comment: Are you trying to scrape from a site where you need to log in? If so, this almost certainly will not work. If the site has an API, that's the way to go.

Comment: No, no need to login and also they don't have any API